# Can't find System.Windows in Add Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I created a new file-system based web site in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010). On property pages I've set to use [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0, but I cannot find `System.Windows` in the Add Reference dialog. The only copy on my PC seems to be in this directory, but this is not a [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) project

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0
```

I thought it might have something to do with the client profile vs full version, but I can't see where to specify that in a web site project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all namespaces have corresponding DLL file names used in the Add Reference dialog. System.Windows is one of these.

For example, `System.Windows.Clipboard` is resident in the PresentationCore.dll, but  `System.Windows.SizeConverter` is in WindowsBase.dll. It all depends on the actual types you need to access.

Comment: That is true for WPF but System.Windows is the silverlight assembly containing the WPF/Silverlight base classes.

Comment: Boy that makes things really confusing. So although there is a System.Windows.dll specifically for SL, it doesn't contain the namespaces I need, which are then found in PresentationCore.dll.  Surprising too that the namespaces I need for some drawing code in a web site are in a WPF specific DLL... Oh well, every day is a school day.

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows is the WPF base classes - you cant add that assembly to an ASP.NET site.  You will need to change your application type to use it.

Comment: Just found that adding PresentationCore.dll and WindowsBase.dll to the bin dir solved this reference problem. Funny.

Comment: @Graeme - Odd indeed - Cant think what you could do with WPF classes in an ASP.NET application but I am a WPF dev and not ASP.NET :).